# Redshift/Flux/brightness-controller Stopped Working

Tags: 16.04, display, screen, brightness, redshift

I haven't used Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on my laptop for a while. Today, after I performed a system upgrade, it seems that neither [Redshift](http://jonls.dk/redshift/) nor [Flux](https://justgetflux.com/linux.html) is able to change the screen color anymore. There's just nothing happening on the screen at all after I ran the commands.

Curiously, the screen color of the external monitor is changed just fine, it's just the built-in screen that's not responsive.

The `brightness-controller` utility is also not working, although the brightness control from system settings is.

They were definitely working well a few weeks ago.

In flux the following messages are shown:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fluxgui/fluxapp.py:75: GtkWarning: Cannot transform xsetting Net/IconThemeName of type gchararray to type GdkColor

gtk.gdk.screen_get_default().get_setting('gtk-icon-theme-name')
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fluxgui/fluxapp.py:75: GtkWarning: Cannot transform xsetting Net/IconThemeName of type gchararray to type gint

gtk.gdk.screen_get_default().get_setting('gtk-icon-theme-name')
```

which I'm not sure if is related to the issue or not.

I've seen a similar [bug report](https://github.com/xflux-gui/xflux-gui/issues/27) on Github.

Did anybody else have this issue? Maybe some system package upgrade broke an interface that all these applications previously used?

My laptop runs on Intel Skylake and GTX980M.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that this is because of a recent kernel change, see here:
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2333398

See if you have kernel 4.4.0-34 (you can do so with the command 'uname -a'). I was unable to find if a bug has been filed for this, so you may want to do so.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I've filed a bug report at https://bugs.launchpad.net/launchpad/+bug/1617686

Comment: I tested and found 4.4.0-34 has this issue, but from 4.4.0-36 and up, the issue no longer exist. @JIXiang, can you confirm this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on my 16.04 system. I removed the pulseaudio system and all of its' dependencies from my computer and then flux started working! I then reinstalled pulseaudio & the desktop and flux is still working like a champ! Hopefully it can work for you too!

Answer (score 0):

I faced with similar problem after upgrading to [Ubuntu 16.04](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/contribute?version=16.04.1&architecture=amd64). The solution at least for now would be to quit redshift from the top panel and launch it again.